# I want to get the value from one class (SearchTableViewController.m) to another class (HistoryTableViewController.m)

Tags: objective-c, iphone

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class SearchDetailViewController;

@interface SearchTableViewController : UITableViewController 
<UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{

 IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
 NSMutableArray *tableData;//will be storing data that will be displayed in table. //Search array den buna aktarma yapcaz ilerde görceksin.
 NSMutableArray *searchedData;//will be storing data matching with the search string
 UISearchBar *sBar;//search bar

 NSMutableArray *searchArray; // It holds the medicines that are shown in tableview
 SearchDetailViewController * searchDetailViewController;

 NSMutableArray *deneme;


}

@property(nonatomic,retain)UISearchBar *sBar;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *tableData;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *searchedData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *searchArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) SearchDetailViewController *searchDetailViewController;


@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *deneme;
@end
```

---

SearchTableViewController.m

---

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
 // AnotherViewController *anotherViewController = [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherView" bundle:nil];
 // [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController];
 // [anotherViewController release];


 **deneme= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 deneme=[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];**

 ****NSLog(@"my row = %@", deneme);**// I holded one of the selected cells here**
```

---

HistoryTableViewController.m

---

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
 // AnotherViewController *anotherViewController = [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherView" bundle:nil];
 // [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController];
 // [anotherViewController release];

 **SearchTableViewController *obj= [[SearchTableViewController alloc]init];**
 **NSLog(@"my 2nd row= %@", [obj deneme]); //it prints nil**


}
```

My project is TabBar. There are two buttons on it- Search and History. I want to display selected items in a table in History tab. But i can not bring the selected item from SearchTableViewController.m to the class (HistoryTableViewController.m)

**The problem is :** I can hold one of the selected items in an array (named deneme)from table in SearchTableViewController.m but i can not take it to HistoryTableViewController.m.
It prints nil in console screen.... If I can make it visible in History class, I display those selected items on table. Please help me !!!

Comment: Are you pushing HistoryTableController from SearchTableViewController or are both in a tab bar controller?

Comment: both are in tabbar controller. One is HistoryTableViewController and the other one is SearchTableViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now in HistoryTableViewController in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, it is creating  a new instance of SearchTableViewController so the array will be empty.  To reference the one in the tab bar, try this:

```
SearchTableViewController *obj = (SearchTableViewController *)[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"my 2nd row= %@", [obj deneme]);
```

Above code assumes SearchTableViewController is at index 0 in your tab bar.  If not, change it accordingly.

Even with the correct index, the array might still be nil if deneme has not yet been set by the SearchTableViewController.

---

Edit: Some advice...

1. Please read (or re-read) the docs on Tab
   Bar Controllers:

   - the [Overview](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH102-SW1)
   - the [Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITabBarController)
2. Although the original code suggestion should work, consider using better approaches to sharing data across controllers:

   - properties in the AppDelegate, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363777/iphone-how-to-pass-data-between-several-viewcontrollers-in-a-tabbar-app/2364524#2364524) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336976/simple-mvc-setup-design/2337375#2337375) (both are answers by @TechZen)
   - [Singleton class](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html)

Those aren't the only two alternates for sharing data but are relatively easy to implement.

Comment: I can catch the row touched by the user in SearchTableViewController.m (already NSLog proves it, i can see that selected item name in console in SearchTableViewController.m) How can i take that value to HistoryTableViewController.m. I think this is more explanatory ... thanx

Comment: Replace how you are setting obj in didSelectRowAtIndexPath in HistoryTableViewController with the example I provided.  Don't alloc+init it, instead get a reference to it from the tabBarController.

Comment: if i send you my project, could you help me ??

Comment: @ahmet732: What happens when you change the code in HistoryTableViewController as shown above?

Comment: It throws an exception when I click on History tab button .(I put the code you wrote in ViewDidLoad to see the change) and I could not specify the number in objectAtIndex. How can I find that? Is it ObjectID in Inspector? I want to sum up my question : Is there any way to access any item in Table View from seperate class?

Comment: No not the ObjectID.  Will edit answer shortly with more advice.

Comment: ı did read your advices thank you very much.. I think objectAtIndex:0 is fine but it throws exception :

Comment: 2010-04-08 17:13:20.120 MaSystemGui[2216:20b] *** -[SearchNavController deneme]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3d1d6b0
2010-04-08 17:13:20.121 MaSystemGui[2216:20b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[SearchNavController deneme]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3d1d6b0'
2010-04-08 17:13:20.123 MaSystemGui[2216:20b] Stack: (

Comment: Why does it say SearchNavController?  Isn't it supposed to be SearchTableViewController?

Comment: When I clicked on the item in Tableview, it navigates to another view and turn back to table view when i clicked on search button on navigation controller.. I replaced SearchTableViewController with SearchNavController (while creating obj thing) but it throws the same exception.. I am indeed going crazy :) it is my senior project. It must be completed till last day of April.. You helped me lot thanx for that..

Comment: The error means that SearchNavController does not have the property deneme like SearchTableViewController does.

Comment: I will take "deneme" property to SearchNavController.h .. What will happen next we will see... But I CAN'T. I am holding the value of on cell in SearchTableViewController.m. It is useless if I take it inside SearchNavController.m.

Comment: I suggest you use one of the alternate methods listed in the edited answer.  But first, clearly plan out your app design rather than making random changes.